# learnyounode JUGGLING ASYNC order is unstable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying learnyounode(https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode)
Exercise 9 ##JUGGLING ASYNC (try 3 get request and show response in the same order)

I wrote below code but result order is not stable. What's is wrong?

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');

var urls = [];

for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++ ) {
  urls.push(process.argv[i]);
};

var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  http.get(urls[i], function(response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
      };

// if this code results[i] = data.toString() // console.log shows “”    
      results.splice(i, 0 , data.toString());

      if ( results.length === urls.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length ; i++) {
          console.log(results[i]);
        }
      };
    }));
  });
}
```

official answer is below.

```
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')
var results = []
var count = 0

function printResults () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(results[i])
  }
}

function httpGet (index) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err)
      }

      results[index] = data.toString()
      count++

      if (count === 3) {
        printResults()
      }
    }))
  })
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  httpGet(i)
}
```

Comment: I would not use the same counter name `i`in nested loops

Comment: and you are creating a closure around the first loop variable `i` in your response-callback. When the callback is evaluated, the value of `i` will be `urls.length-1` in each execution.

Comment: thank you for your answers. I modify index to unique value (i,j,k) but order was not improved.